# PIC16F886 - set configuration bits

Tags: config, pic, microchip

I am getting syntax errors while trying to set the configuration bits on a PIC16F886. 
The problem is that there are two configuration words and two configurations have multiple bits. 
So it does not work the way it works with PIC10F206. 
I am using the pic-as v2.20 toolchain.

```
PROCESSOR 16F886
RADIX DEC
    
#include <xc.inc>
 
;this did not work:
;config DEBUG = ON, LVP = OFF, FCMEN = OFF, IESO = OFF, BOREN = OFF
;config CPD = OFF, CP = OFF, MCLRE = OFF, PWRTE = OFF, WDTE = OFF, FOSC = OFF
    
;this did not work:    
;config 0000000000000000000000000000
 
;this did not work:
;config 0x00

;this did not work:
;config config1 0x0000
;config config2 0x0000
    
    
    PSECT   StartCode,class=CODE,delta=2
    global  Start
Start:
    movlw 11000000B  ;set option register
    ;option is not in the p16f886 instruction summary
    movwf 81h  ;option_reg is at 81h (bank 1)
    
    movlw 11111110B  ;everything to input except for RA0
    tris 05h  ;05h is TRISA
    
    bcf 05h, 0  ;clear bit zero in TRISA register
    ;the led on RA0 should light up now
    
    sleep

END Start
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? What assembler are you using? The old MPASM or the new XC8 assembler?

Comment: ```p16f886_light_up.s:8:: error: (1363) unknown configuration setting/register (FOSC = OFF) used``` and ```:37:: warning: (1311) missing configuration setting for config word 0x2008; using default``` I am using the new pic-as v2.20 toolchain.

Comment: `OFF` is not a valid option for `FOSC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. 
This code here works so far. 
It is still not perfect like I probably should use the `BANKSEL`directive and use the variables instead of hex codes. 
Also I did not set bank 1 before setting the options so that might not have an effect.

```
PROCESSOR 16F886
PAGEWIDTH   132
RADIX DEC
    
#include <xc.inc>
 
config DEBUG = OFF, LVP = OFF, FCMEN = OFF, IESO = OFF, BOREN = OFF
config CPD = OFF, CP = OFF, MCLRE = OFF, PWRTE = OFF, WDTE = OFF
config FOSC = INTRC_NOCLKOUT, LVP = OFF, BOR4V = BOR40V, WRT = OFF
    
    
    PSECT   StartCode,class=CODE,delta=2
    global  Start
Start:
    movlw 11000000B  ;set option register
    ;option is not in the p16f886 instruction summary
    movwf 81h  ;option_reg is at 81h (bank 1)
    
    movlw 00100000B  ;set the status register (select bank 1)
    movwf 03h  ;status register is at 03h
    
    movlw 11111110B  ;everything to input except for RA0
    ;there is no tris instruction on this processor
    movwf 85h  ;85h is TRISA register
    
    movlw 00000000B  ;set the status register (select bank 0)
    movwf 03h  ;status register is at 03h
    
    ;05h is PORTA
    bcf 05h, 0  ;clear bit zero in PORTA register
    ;the led on RA0 should light up now
    
    sleep

END Start
```

Comment: Register names are already defined in xc.inc. You don't need to use hex address values.

Comment: Please see the data memory map (Figure 2-4) in the datasheet. You need to switch banks to access `OPTION_REG` and `TRISA`. I don't know how your LED is connected but clearing a bit in PORT registers makes the output low (connected to GND). Actually, PORT registers are all zero on powerup by default.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a problem that trips up most people new to Microchip controllers. GPIO pins with analog functionality do not work very well until configured for digital mode.

This code will setup PORTA bit RA0 as a digital output and toggle it high and low about 2 times per second.

```
;
; File:     main.S
; Target:   PIC16F886
; Author:   dan1138
; Date:     2020-09-08
; Compiler: pic-as(v2.20)
; IDE:      MPLABX v5.40
;
; Description:
;
;   Example project for the PIC16F886 controller using the pic-as(v2.20) tool chain.
;
; Add this line in the project properties box, pic-as Global Options -> Additional options:
;   -Wa,-a -Wl,-pPor_Vec=0h,-pIsr_Vec=4h
;
    PROCESSOR   16F886
    PAGEWIDTH   132
    RADIX       DEC

#include <xc.inc>

; CONFIG1
 config FOSC = INTRC_NOCLKOUT; Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSCIO oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
 config WDTE = OFF       ; Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled and can be enabled by SWDTEN bit of the WDTCON register)
 config PWRTE = OFF      ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
 config MCLRE = ON       ; RE3/MCLR pin function select bit (RE3/MCLR pin function is MCLR)
 config CP = OFF         ; Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
 config CPD = OFF        ; Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
 config BOREN = OFF      ; Brown Out Reset Selection bits (BOR disabled)
 config IESO = OFF       ; Internal External Switchover bit (Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled)
 config FCMEN = OFF      ; Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)
 config LVP = OFF        ; Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB3 pin has digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)

; CONFIG2
 config BOR4V = BOR21V   ; Brown-out Reset Selection bit (Brown-out Reset set to 2.1V)
 config WRT = OFF        ; Flash Program Memory Self Write Enable bits (Write protection off)

;
; Define macros to help with
; bank selection
;
#define BANK0  (0x000)
#define BANK1  (0x080)
#define BANK2  (0x100)
#define BANK3  (0x180)
;
; Skip macros
;
  skipnc  MACRO
    btfsc   STATUS,STATUS_C_POSITION
  ENDM

  skipc  MACRO
    btfss   STATUS,STATUS_C_POSITION
  ENDM

  skipnz  MACRO
    btfsc   STATUS,STATUS_Z_POSITION
  ENDM

  skipz  MACRO
    btfss   STATUS,STATUS_Z_POSITION
  ENDM
;
; Power-On-Reset entry point
;
    PSECT   Por_Vec,global,class=CODE,delta=2
    global  resetVec
resetVec:
    PAGESEL Start
    goto    Start

;
;   Data space use by interrupt handler to save context
    PSECT   Isr_Data,global,class=COMMON,space=1,delta=1,noexec
;
    GLOBAL  WREG_save,STATUS_save,PCLATH_save
;
WREG_save:      DS  1
STATUS_save:    DS  1
PCLATH_save:    DS  1
;
;   Interrupt vector and handler
    PSECT   Isr_Vec,global,class=CODE,delta=2
    GLOBAL  IsrVec
;
IsrVec:
    movwf   WREG_save
    swapf   STATUS,W
    movwf   STATUS_save
    movf    PCLATH,W
    movwf   PCLATH_save
;
IsrHandler:
;
IsrExit:
    movf    PCLATH_save,W
    movwf   PCLATH
    swapf   STATUS_save,W
    movwf   STATUS
    swapf   WREG_save,F
    swapf   WREG_save,W
    retfie                      ; Return from interrupt
;
; Initialize the PIC hardware
;
Start:
    clrf    INTCON              ; Disable all interrupt sources
    banksel BANK1
    clrf    PIE1
    clrf    PIE2

    movlw   0b01100000
    movwf   OSCCON              ; Set internal oscillator at 4MHz

    movlw   0b10000001          ; Pull-ups off, INT edge high to low, WDT prescale 1:1
    movwf   OPTION_REG          ; TMR0 clock edge low to high, TMR0 clock = FCY, TMR0 prescale 1:4
                                ; TIMER0 will assert the overflow flag every 256*4 (1024)
                                ; instruction cycles, with a 4MHz oscilator this ia 1.024 milliseconds.

    movlw   0b11111111         ;
    movwf   TRISA

    movlw   0b11111111         ;
    movwf   TRISB

    movlw   0b11111111         ;
    movwf   TRISC

    ; Set all ADC inputs for digital I/O
    banksel BANK3
    movlw   0b00000000
    movwf   ANSEL
    movlw   0b00000000
    movwf   ANSELH
    banksel BANK2
    clrf    CM1CON0             ; turn off comparator
    clrf    CM2CON0             ; turn off comparator
    banksel BANK1
    movlw   0b00000000
    movwf   ADCON1
    clrf    VRCON               ; turn off voltage reference
    banksel BANK0
    movlw   0b10000000
    movwf   ADCON0

    pagesel main
    goto    main
;
; Main application data
;
    PSECT   MainData,global,class=RAM,space=1,delta=1,noexec
    global  count
count:  DS      1               ;reserve 1 byte for TOMER0 rollover count
;
; Main application code
;
    PSECT   MainCode,global,class=CODE,delta=2
;
; Function to Wait for TIMER0 to rollover 250 times
;
WaitOnTimer0:
    movlw   250
    BANKSEL count
    movwf   BANKMASK(count)
WaitT0a:
    bcf     INTCON,INTCON_TMR0IF_POSITION
WaitT0b:
    btfss   INTCON,INTCON_TMR0IF_POSITION
    goto    WaitT0b
    decfsz  BANKMASK(count),F
    goto    WaitT0a
    return
;
; Set PORTA bit 0 as an output then set low wait
; for 250 rollovers of TIMER0 and set hihg and
; wait another 250 rollovers of TIMER0 then loop
;
main:
    BANKSEL TRISA
    bcf     BANKMASK(TRISA),TRISA_TRISA0_POSITION   ; Make PORTA bit RA0 an output
loop:
    BANKSEL PORTA
    bcf     BANKMASK(PORTA),PORTA_RA0_POSITION      ; Make PORTA bit RA0 LOW
    call    WaitOnTimer0
    bsf     BANKMASK(PORTA),PORTA_RA0_POSITION      ; Make PORTA bit RA0 HIGH
    call    WaitOnTimer0
    goto    loop
;
; Declare Power-On-Reset entry point
;
    END     resetVec
```

Give this a try and let me know how it goes.